# Meteor publish latest grouped by

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I have a collection that with something like:

```
{
  _id: 'abc',
  _remoteId: 'xyz',
  submitted_on: ISODate('2015-01-24T15:00:39.171Z"');
}
```

Where `_remoteId` is a reference to another collection.  What I need is to publish the latest of documents, grouped by _remoteId.  I think I need to use the `$group` aggregate, but the only examples (example [here](http://joshowens.me/using-mongodb-aggregations-to-power-a-meteor-js-publication/)) seem to not return a Cursor, and thus do not seem to be reactive.  Is there a way to publish a group aggregate in such a way to be reactive, either by returning a Cursor directly or by observing on the server and setting up the updates manually?

Comment: **Moderator note**: Please keep comments civil, constructive and related to clarifying the question **only**. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet in the example that you reference shows how you would create a reactive cursor. He missed returning it though... at the end of the `previousInviteContacts`, he should have returned:

```
return self.ready();
```

Other than that, to consume it, just subscribe to the `previousInviteContacts` publication and query the `contacts` collection.

Comment: The `self.ready()` doesn't make this reactive.  That call merely signals DDP on that the data has been fully sent on initialize.  In that example, there is nothing observing changes to the data.  Once the data is read in, and the `.each` loop is done, what is going to trigger more DDP requests to the client that the data has changed?  For that to happen, you would need something to trigger a `.added()`, '.changed()', and/or `.removed()` call AFTER the publication had already called `.ready()`, right?